# Is there a way to get lists in loops

Tags: r, shiny

I have a list here below

```
params <- list(exp1 = input$exp1, grad_exp1 = input$grad_exp1)
```

But this is hardcoded. Meaning, when the names are more, I need to add it manually. So my plan is to get a vector like below so that the params gets automated with the list

```
experiences <- c("exp1", "grad_exp1")
```

Example

```
experiences <- c("exp1", "grad_exp1", "grad_exp2")
```

Expected output

```
params <- list(exp1 = input$exp1, grad_exp1 = input$grad_exp1, grad_exp2 = input$grad_exp2)
```

Comment: One-liner: `setNames(params <- input[experiences], experiences)`. Or `params <- input[experiences]; names(params) <- experiences`.

Comment: @Rui why do you need to set the names? Seems that `input` is a named list. so  `params <- input[experiences]` will give you a named subset

Comment: @onyambu Yes, you are right, I missed that point. This is mostly a duplicate of [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a vector of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically select data frame columns using $ and a character value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value)